# Logstash got error to send bulk of actions to elasticsearch server at localhost on Windows

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I wrote a .conf file as in the example given in the Logstash documentation and tried to run it. Logstash started but when I gave the input it gave the error as mentioned in the title.

I am using Windows 8.1 and the .conf file in saved in the `logstash-1.5.0/bin`.

Here is the .conf file:

```
input { stdin { } }
output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Here is the screenshot of the command prompt:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, "logstash" should be the same name of your cluster in Elasticsearch.yml

output {

```
  elasticsearch {

  cluster => "logstash"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. It was because I have not installed elasticsearch before running logstash.
Thanks for trying to helping me out